# DirectWrite Producing Strange Artifacts?

Tags: 2d, directx11

I've written the basis to my UI system around Direct2D. I like it because it's fast and easy to use (even if I had to do some messy work to get it to work with DirectX11). However, I notice when using DirectWrite I'm getting strange problems with my text.

[image: Text artifacts]

As you can see, the `e` is a little screwwed up, and it overall looks a little bumpy. This only happens with certain fonts in certain sizes, and with certain arrangements of letters. This particular example is Verdana in size 16.0 font.

Can I fix this? It's pretty annoying to change all my words and fonts because of this problem.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Direct2D/DirectWrite, but is there a way to enable antialiased font rendering?  That might help.  This looks like the font is being drawn at an awkward size that's causing the bar of the e to fall in between pixels and be missed, which antialising should solve.

Comment: @NathanReed I'll search around, but it's not like its being drawn small or anything. Infact, if I shrink it, the problem goes away.

Comment: Oddly, the problem disappeared today. I can't really post an answer because I don't know what fixed it.